Is there a programmatic way to generate s-functions directly out of Simulink blocks
I would require wrapping the logic of my Simulink model to be obfuscated or hidden. One of the ways to perform it is to create a similar s-function block with the object code generated from the same Simulink block. I am facing difficulty in realizing this programmatically. Is there a way around to realize them programmatically or rely on GUI to create manually.

According to Simulink documentation the workflow for model/subsystem for IP protection we can follow https://in.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/generated-s-function-block-deployment.html.

The workflow can be summarized as follows:
Code generation settings:

Change the system target file to 'rtwsfcn.tlc'.
In Code generation settings enable 'create new model'
In Code generation settings uncheck 'Generate code only'.

Once the above steps are done go ahead with building the model block programmatically:
oldBlockPath=getfullname(gcbh);
newBlockHandle=slbuild(gcbh) % gcbh points to handle of current selected block 
newBlockPath=getfullname(newBlockHandle);
pil_block_replace(oldBlockPath,newBlockPath);

The above code snippet can implement the idea at a fundamental level for a selected block.
Reference: MATLAB Answer's

Adding a comment here a similar thread I found in MATLAB Answers. https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/414694-how-can-i-protect-the-intellectual-property-of-my-simulink-model
